# How to write and compile kernel module from multiple sources? (WARNING: "do_function" [... main.ko] undefined)

Tags: c, makefile, kernel, kernel-module

I want to separate my kernel module to sources. But I can't compile it properly.

**print_hello.h**

```
#ifndef PRINT_HELLO_H_
#define PRINT_HELLO_H_
void print_hello(void);
#endif /* PRINT_HELLO_H_ */
```

**print_hello.c:**

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include "print_hello.h"

void print_hello(void) {
  printk("Hello, World!\n");
}
```

**main.c:**

```
#include<linux/module.h>
#include<linux/version.h>
#include<linux/kernel.h>
#include<linux/init.h>

#include "print_hello.h"

int hello_init(void) {
  print_hello();
  return 0;
}

module_init(hello_init);;
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

Makefile:

```
obj-m += main.o
main-objs := print_hello.o main.o 


all:
    make -C /lib/modules/3.2.51/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/3.2.51/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

but when I compile this program this error occur:

```
root@linux:r# make                                                                                                                 
make -C /lib/modules/3.2.51/build M=/home/root/hello modules                                                                                        
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/build'                                                                                                                                   
  CC [M]  /home/root/hello/main.o                                                                                                  
  Building modules, stage 2.                                                                                                                                                   
  MODPOST 1 modules                                                                                                                                                            
WARNING: "print_hello" [/home/root/hello/main.ko] undefined!                                                                       
  LD [M]  /home/root/hello/foo.ko                                                                                                 
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/build'
```

Any solution to solve this problem?

Comment: Cant reproduce the problem.